# Can I automatically pass an existing text into the method parameter?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

For example I have the following block of code:

```
public String getDbSchema() {
    return DB_SCHEMA;
}
```

Is there a shortcut to quickly turn this code into

```
public String getDbSchema() {
    return properties.getProperty(DB_SCHEMA);
}
```

Currently I have to do `properties.getproperty` then take out right bracket and re-insert it into the end of the statement

Comment: So currently you have to type out `properties.getProperty` and you are saying typing that is too slow? And what is this about you having to _take out the right bracket and re-insert it into the end of the statement?_

Comment: @chancea well it was more a case of finding out whether there's a hotkey on intelliJ which I've missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select getProperty from the code completion, instead of pressing Enter, press the shortcut of Edit | Complete Current Statement (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+Enter), and DB_SCHEMA will be wrapped into call parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use a structural find and replace that is a little bit smart.

First, let's presume that this code has the form `return XYZ;` where `XYZ` is a constant identifier (`CAPS` or `_`)

Then you can go into search and replace in files (ctrl+shift+R), tick *Case Sensitive* and *Regular Expression* and enter:

Text to find: `return ([A-Z_]*);`

Replace with: `return properties.getProperty($1);`